# Alert BAsed on IF statement based on Sum by Group?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, group-by, alert

I want to create this alert only if any employees daily hours fall below 6.00, currently my code is tallying all of the hours of all employees, how do create the alert for only each employee

```
declare @totalhrs int
SELECT @totalhrs = SUM(duration) 
FROM pl00.DBO.schedule
where (schedule.DATE  = CONVERT(char(10), getdate()+2, 121)
and schedule.TYPE <> 'z')
group by EMP_ID, schedule.DATE

    if(@totalhrs < 6) 
    begin

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = 'mail.pacificlawnsprinklers.com',
    @recipients = 'mmahoney@pacificlawnsprinklers.com',
    @query = '

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT EMP_ID, DateName(weekday, Cast(schedule.DATE AS date)),schedule.[DATE], SUM(duration) as TotalHrs 
    FROM pl00.DBO.schedule
    where (schedule.DATE  = CONVERT(char(10), getdate()+2, 121)
    and schedule.TYPE <> "Z")
    group by EMP_ID, schedule.DATE
    ',
    @subject = 'Lights Lists to Review',
    @attach_query_result_as_file = 0 ;

    end
```

Comment: This would be one of the rare times where a cursor is appropriate. You first need a list of all EMP_IDs to send an email too. Then add another predicate to the query for the EMP_ID. Loop through the list sending an email for each recipient along th way.

Comment: I am not looking to email each person.  I want to first only alert myself if ANY of the tech have a duration < 6 not a sum of all technicians, then i wan to select ONLY the techs with a duration sum less than 6

Comment: Gotcha. The easy way to determine if ANY of them have a duration < 6 is to use EXISTS. Then you can get all the names using a standard select statement. If you want help with the actual coding you should start here. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: but i need sum of duration per employee not for the entire query, i need it on change of employee

Comment: To get sum by employee you would use a group by.

Answer (score 0):

remove mysql tag.

Try this query:

```
SELECT EMP_ID, DateName(weekday, Cast(schedule.DATE AS date)), SUM(duration) as TotalHrs 
FROM pl00.DBO.schedule
where (schedule.DATE  = CONVERT(char(10), getdate()+2, 121) -- ?
and schedule.TYPE <> "Z")
group by EMP_ID, Cast(schedule.DATE AS date)
HAVING SUM(duration) > 6
```

Comment: Okay so this worked for whats is displaying but is there away to get the alert part of the function to only send the email if the condtion of any employee with duration sum < 6 then it triggers list

Comment: There is not enough information to answer on this question. Is there any application to send this alert. What programming language, code you have in this app, how you need send alert etc...

Comment: its in my original code, i'm doing an IF statement to trigger the query which would be sent in an email, but if i cannot get the if statement to look at total duration per employee to be over 6 then i cannot trigger email properly

Comment: You application base only on stored procedures? You can build trigger on `insert or update` table that contain employee duration time, an test `if @var_sum_of_duration > 6` or `if exists(...)` result of my query for employee then do_alert()...